# Two way binding is not happening between Tree view and combo box in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control which has  a tree view and a combo box.Tree view  has items source bound  using view model class.Combo box item source is given through code behind.I have bound Selected Id path  as two way binding between Combo box and tree view.Now when application run, when  control has populated and displayed data and when ever I select any item in Treeview..combox box item is getting selected.But when I select any item from combo box , corresponding item is not getting selected in the treeview..though it two way binding..please help me to fix this issue ..my objective is when ever user select any item in combo box , the same item should be selected in tree view
My User control :

```
  <UserControl x:Class="gsktid.MyUserControl.TreeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gsktid.MyUserControl"
          xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:gsktid.ViewModel" 
          xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Text="Search:" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSerchBox" Width="120" DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName"  SelectedIndex = "-1"   SelectedValuePath = "Id"  SelectedValue="{Binding  Path=SelectedId,Mode=TwoWay}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8"  >
  Path=SelectedId}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>-->
    </ComboBox>
    <TreeView Height="500" x:Name="tvMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" MaxHeight="25" MaxWidth="25"/>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">            
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} ">
                            <Binding Path="FirstName"/>

                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tvMain, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>


</StackPanel>
```

My code behind of this user control is :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using gsktid.ViewModel;
using gsktid.Model;
namespace gsktid.MyUserControl
 {

     public partial class TreeView : UserControl
{
    public TreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = OrgTreeViewModel.Instance();
        cmbSerchBox.ItemsSource = OrgChartManager.Instance().GetChildrenSerch();

    }
}
```

}

---

Here Combobox is poulated wit dataset by giving the item source in code behind.But Treeview 's item source is populated through view model data set.Both data set is having one common key .That is how the when I select the item in the tree view corresponding item in the combo box is getting selected.But vice versa is not happening.When I select one item in the combo box , the corresponding item in the tree view is getting selected even though it two way binding

What I have tried:

I have tried to bind between combo box and Tree view..as two way binding  ..but it is working one way .when   ever I makes selection changes in Treeview it is reflecting in the combo  box..but when I makes selection changes in the combo box it is not affecting tree view

Comment: I think you're unlikely to get an answer to this question as it stands.  You have missing code, errors in the XAML, and you haven't shown how the data contexts are hooked up.  I can't see how the combo is even populated.

What we need to help is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The best way to create one here would be to start a new project, add in just the bits of code that are relevant to the problem, and make it work with some mock data to show the issue.  That's what anyone helping is having to do, after all.

Comment: Thanks for giving the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wasn't what I meant!  I meant we need something where we can create a new Visual Studio WPF Application project, paste the code in, run, and see the problem.  You can't do that with the code in the current question, right?

I understand that that isn't particularly easy with the original code though.   However, I actually created a version myself earlier today.  It isn't perfect, because I can't see all your code, so I've had to guess in a few places.

This code is at the very bottom of this answer.  This is what we mean by a minimal reproducible example.

If you create a new project and paste the code at the bottom into the MainWindow XAML and C# files it will show a user control with a combobox and a treeview, and clicking in either will select the correct item in the other.  It's based on your original code, and the XAML is almost identical.  Actually you do need to install the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf NuGet package as well, because your XAML uses behaviors.

The problem in your original question was that the IsSelected property on the appropriate OrgElementViewModel item in the TreeView was not being set when the ComboBox was changed.  This was because the only property that was being updated when the ComboBox changed was SelectedId.

The solution below is to use the setter of SelectedId to update the IsSelected property and for completeless the Selected item in the OrgTreeViewModel, if you're still with me.  The important code is immediately below, which is replacing the existing SelectedId code in OrgTreeViewModel:

```
    public string SelectedId
    {
        get { return selectedId; }
        set
        {
            selectedId = value;
            OrgElementViewModel orgElementViewModel = FindById(selectedId);
            if (orgElementViewModel != null) this.Selected = orgElementViewModel;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedId");
        }
    }
```

Note that this has a FindById method that needs to take the selectedId and find the appropriate OrgElementViewModel item in the tree.  I can't see a method that does this and it's a little tricky to write one without your working code: there's almost certainly a better way of doing it than the recursive search in the solution below.  Also I couldn't work out how the combo was populated so created my own list and bound to it.

Let me know if that helps!

Full working example: XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ComboTreeBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboTreeBinding"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Text="Search:" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbSerchBox" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName"  SelectedIndex = "-1"   SelectedValuePath = "Id"  SelectedValue="{Binding  Path=SelectedId,Mode=TwoWay}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8"  >
        </ComboBox>
        <TreeView Height="150" x:Name="tvMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0} ">
                                    <Binding Path="FirstName"/>

                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Style>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tvMain, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TreeView>


    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Full working example, C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ComboTreeBinding
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new OrgTreeViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class OrgTreeViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public OrgTreeViewModel()
        {
            this.CreateDataList();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> List { get; set; }
        private List<OrgElementViewModel> root;
        public List<OrgElementViewModel> Root
        {
            get
            {
                if (root == null) root = new List<OrgElementViewModel>{List[0]};
                return root;
            }
        }

        public void CreateDataList()
        {
            ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> list = new ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel>();
            list.Add(new OrgElementViewModel("1", "AAAAA", "0"));
            list.Add(new OrgElementViewModel("2", "BBBBB", "1"));
            list.Add(new OrgElementViewModel("3", "CCCCC", "1"));
            list.Add(new OrgElementViewModel("7", "DDDDD", "2"));
            this.List = list;
            foreach (OrgElementViewModel item in list) SetChildren(item);
        }

        private void SetChildren(OrgElementViewModel Parent)
        {
            foreach (OrgElementViewModel listItem in List)
            {
                if (listItem.ParentId == Parent.Id) Parent.Children.Add(listItem);
            }
        }

        private ICommand selectedCommand;
        public ICommand SelectedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (selectedCommand == null)
                {
                    selectedCommand = new CommandBase(i => this.SetSelected(i), null);
                }

                return selectedCommand;
            }
        }

        private void SetSelected(object orgElement)
        {
            this.Selected = orgElement as OrgElementViewModel;
            SelectedId = this.Selected.Id;

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedId");

        }

        private OrgElementViewModel selected;
        public OrgElementViewModel Selected
        {
            get { return selected; }
            set
            {
                selected = value;
                selected.IsSelected = true;
                //ShowChildrenLevel();  //show only the levels chosen by the user
                OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }

        private string selectedId;
        public string SelectedId
        {
            get { return selectedId; }
            set
            {
                selectedId = value;
                OrgElementViewModel orgElementViewModel = FindById(selectedId);
                if (orgElementViewModel != null) this.Selected = orgElementViewModel;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedId");
            }
        }

        private OrgElementViewModel FindById(string ID)
        {
            foreach(OrgElementViewModel item in this.List)
            {
                if (item.Id == ID) return item;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class OrgElementViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string ParentId { get; set; }
        private bool isSelected;
        public ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel> Children { get; set; }
        public OrgElementViewModel(string Id, string FirstName, string ParentId)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.FirstName = FirstName;
            this.ParentId = ParentId;
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<OrgElementViewModel>();
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class CommandBase : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> commandDelegate;
        private object commandParameter;

        public CommandBase(Action<object> commandDelegate, object commandParameter)
        {
            this.commandDelegate = commandDelegate;
            this.commandParameter = commandParameter;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            commandDelegate?.Invoke(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```